# Twins in Prolog will repeat answer

Tags: prolog

Let's say that I have 3 childrens

```
person(pet,fox,date(5,may,2004),unemployed).  
person(jim,fox,date(5,may,2004),unemployed).  
person(george,fox,date(9,december,2002),unemployed).  

child(X):-X=person(pet,fox,date(5,may,2004),unemployed).  
child(X):-X=person(jim,fox,date(5,may,2004),unemployed).  
child(X):-X=person(george,fox,date(9,december,2002),unemployed).
```

I want to get the twins of these childrens

```
twins(Child1,Child2) :-
    child(Child1),child(Child2),
    Child1=person(Fname1,_,Date1,_),
    Child2=person(Fname2,_,Date2,_),
    Fname1\=Fname2,
    Date1=Date2.
```

The problem is when I ask prolog twins(X,Y). I will get some answers again. How to prevent that?

```
?- twins(X,Y).  
X = person(pet, fox, date(5, may, 2004), unemployed),  
Y = person(jim, fox, date(5, may, 2004), unemployed) ;  
X = person(jim, fox, date(5, may, 2004), unemployed),  
Y = person(pet, fox, date(5, may, 2004), unemployed) ;  
false.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent generation of all permutations by imposing a non-symmetrical order on the elements of the pair:

```
?- twins(X, Y), X @< Y.
X = person(jim, fox, date(5, may, 2004), unemployed),
Y = person(pet, fox, date(5, may, 2004), unemployed) ;
false.
```

This only eliminates unwanted solutions from this query, but to achieve this on every call to `twins/2` you can just replace `\=` inside the definition of `twins/2` by `@<`. (Two terms in the `@<` relation are automatically unequal in the sense of `\=` unless one of them is a variable.)

As another comment, the duplication of your database as both `person/4` facts and as data inside the clauses of `child/1` is strange, unnecessary, and very error-prone. You could replace your three-clause definition of `child/1` with this single clause that refers to your `person/4` database:

```
child(X) :-
    person(FirstName, LastName, DOB, Status),
    X = person(FirstName, LastName, DOB, Status).
```